# In pascal, how can I check if real variable is in range?

Tags: pascal

In any other language it's simple, but in Pascal I still have problems. With integer variables, I want to read from user value between `1` and `12`, so I simply do:

```
Program HelloWorld(output);

{$mode objFPC}

var
    a: integer;

begin
     repeat
        writeln('Provide a, a in [1,12]:');
        readln(a);   
     until (a in [1..12]);    
end.
```

What if I want to check, if `a` is in `[0,3.14159]`? So basically `a` is `real` not `integer`. How to solve something like this?

Comment: Define an InRange funtion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator in pascal is not checking *ranges*  but *sets* so

```
a in [1..12]
```

does not check if `a` is in a range of 1..12 but checks whether `a` is in a set constructed from the `Integer`s from 1..12. This would be quite problematic for `Real` values.

So the only consistent way would be checking

```
(a >= 0) and (a <= 3.14159)
```

Of course you can create a respective function if you want.

```
function inrange(val, lower, upper: real): boolean;
begin
  inrange := (lower <= val) and (upper >= val);
end;


var a: real;
begin
  repeat
    writeln('Provide a, a in [0, 3.14159]:');
    readln(a);   
  until inrange(a, 0, 3.14159);  
end.
```

Comment: This code: https://onlinegdb.com/QTSTD-Q5- gives me this: `
main.pas(12,14) Error: Incompatible types: got "Boolean" expected "Extended"`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the parenthesis ... My pascal is a bit rusty ...

Comment: Since Brian Brown is using the FPC, I’d suggest to use [`math.inRange`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/rtl/math/inrange.html) instead of “reinventing” your own `function`. [I would’ve added that comment to your post, but the “Suggested edit queue is full”.]